# why does my events load after i click the next button full calendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Im using 2 fullcalendar. I'm so confused why my events in my 2nd calendar is not loading. This is the code of my 2nd calendar.

```
 ` $("#calendar-modal").html("");
                    var scheduleClick=info.event.start.toISOString();
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar-modal');
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                            plugins: [ 'timeGrid' ],
                            header: {
                                left: false,
                                center: 'title',
                                right: false
                            },
                            defaultView:'timeGrid',
                            defaultDate:scheduleClick,
                            displayEventTime:false,
                            allDaySlot: false,
                            slotEventOverlap:false,
                            minTime:"07:00",
                            maxTime:"24:00",
                            eventSources:[
                               {
                               url:'something.php',
                               method:'POST',
                               color: '#87a900',  
                               textColor: 'black'
                               }
                               ],
                    });  
                    calendar.refetchEvents(); // I've tried using refetch events
                    calendar.render();`
```

I hope someone can clarify my mistake in this code. I've searched about this topic and i have seen something related to next and prev buttons. Does the calendar only render events after clicking next and prev?

Comment: `calendar.refetchEvents(); // I've tried using refetch events
                    calendar.render();` are not necessary, and neither is pressing next/prev. fullCalendar will contact your server to fetch events from the defined event source as soon as the calendar is loaded. If you watch your Network section (in your browser's Developer Tools) while your code is running you should see the request to "something.php" being made as soon as the calendar loads. I can only assume maybe your server is not providing the correct response in some way (e.g. error, or wrong data or something)

Comment: ...You can find that out by clicking on the request to "something.php" in the Network tool and looking at the raw response received. You'll need to check whether it contains what you expected it to, or not. This is a fairly basic JavaScript debugging technique which you need to understand and able to use if you want to write browser-based applications successfully. Debugging of AJAX requests is a key skill, almost all modern web applications use it. Please take the time to learn now. P.S. There's nothing obviously wrong with your actual calendar code, as far as I can see.

Comment: the code i posted is inside the eventClick: Function(info)

Comment: Yes I know (from one of your other questions) it's inside the eventClick of another calendar. But that isn't relevant to anything I wrote above. I'm talking about the calendar you've written about in the question. Did you do the debugging I described? What was the result?

Comment: i did, The response is `[{"title":"","start":"2019-06-20T07:00:00","end":"2019-06-20T12:00:00"},{"title":"","start":"2019-06-20T12:00:00","end":"2019-06-20T21:00:00"}]` I think the calendar read it. But It doesn't load whenever i click the event, But when i add next or prev button then click it that is the time the events will load.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem, to be honest, here's a demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JQEorr . It works fine when you click on an event on a day where the JSON source has events (the 20th, in this case. If you click the others, the JSON has no events for them, so the calendar is empty.). I have no idea what you're doing wrong in your version.